# Android, show menu items with title

Tags: java, android, menu

I have this menu:

[image]

When clicked I want this menu to shown up:

[image]

Instead with my current code, that is what shown:

[image]

Only when the above clicked, the second image is shown.

I want that after I click the menu image(first image) the second image menu will be shown.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Filter by">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="Age">
                <menu>
                    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                        <item
                            android:id="@+id/action_20_25"
                            android:title="20 - 25" />
                        <item
                            android:id="@+id/action_30_40"
                            android:title="30 - 40" />
                    </group>
                </menu>
            </item>
            <item android:title="Location">
                <menu>
                    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                        <item
                            android:id="@+id/action_filter_thirty_minutes"
                            android:title="30 min" />
                        <item
                            android:id="@+id/action_filter_forty_five_minutes"
                            android:title="45 min" />
                    </group>
                </menu>
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I did try to add `app:showAsAction="always"`(app prefix is due to the use of the support library) to the item where the title is `Filter by` but that is what I get instead of the 3 dots(first picture) is:

[image]

Comment: The behavior is ok because that is a submenu you are implementing. Try putting items in a group and give a title to the group

Comment: @Laser hi, thanks for the comment, can you answer with a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

app:showAsAction="always". This means that it will always be showed in the action bar.

Use app:showAsAction="never" to get your item in the overflow menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:title="Filter by"
    app:showAsAction="never">
    <menu>
        <item android:title="Age">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/action_20_25"
                        android:title="20 - 25" />
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/action_30_40"
                        android:title="30 - 40" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
        <item android:title="Location">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/action_filter_thirty_minutes"
                        android:title="30 min" />
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/action_filter_forty_five_minutes"
                        android:title="45 min" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Just copy the code. This will always show your option (filter by) in overflow menu.

Comment: can you explain with a code sample, where should I put the `showAsAction` with `never`?

Comment: @AvielFedidai Sorry for the late reply. I have added the code sample above.

Comment: Hi, I've copy>past the code but it's working the same(third picture then second picture), I'm looking for first picture click, then second picture appears.

Comment: This can be achieved using dialog boxes. You can see how youtube app does it. It may help.
Here, best you can do is to use a filter icon and make it app:showAsAction="always". Then by just clicking that icon you will get the second picture.